Degrees of irreducible polynomials over finite fields
Artin chapter 15 states the following as a corollary:

Corollary 15.7.4   For every positive integer $r$, there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $r$ over the prime field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Does this also imply that there exists an irreducible polynomial of arbitrary degree over all finite fields?  For example, given an extension $L/K$ of finite fields, where $|K|=p^{r_1}$ and $|L|=p^{r_2}$, does the corollary imply the existence of a polynomial of degree $r_2/r_1$ in $K[x]$?
I know that the irreducible factors of $x^{p^{r_2}}-x$ are the irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ with degrees dividing $r_2$, so essentially I'm wondering whether replacing the prime field with another field of characteristic $p$ changes the validity of that statement.
